# CAST as TIMESTAMP not working for some string formats

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a field in a BigQuery table that is a STRING but is actually a timestamp, of the format "2019-06-14T11:31:07". So I am using CAST(sign_up_date AS TIMESTAMP) to convert to a usable TIMESTAMP.

This works perfectly in Legacy SQL, however, in Standard SQL, it brings up errors when the STRING is of the format "2019-06-14T09:09" (on the exact minute, missing ":00") or "2019-05-25T05:31:22.7263555" (as sometimes they come through with decimal seconds).

Any idea on how I can get it to work in Standard SQL? Obviously I could just use Legacy SQL, but I want to write in Standard as there are other functionns that work better in that one.

Thanks,

Benji

Comment: Use `parse_timestamp()` rather than `cast()`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but this is not working for all the data types, as some of them are not exactly like above, and so says it can't parse "2016-08-15 13:23:00" or "2016-08-15 13:23:00+00". Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "2019-06-14T11:31:07" sign_up_date UNION ALL
  SELECT "2019-05-25T05:31:22.7263555" UNION ALL
  SELECT "2019-06-14T09:09"
)
SELECT sign_up_date, 
  COALESCE(
    SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%R', sign_up_date),
    SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%R:%E*S', sign_up_date)  
  ) AS sign_up_date_as_timestamp  
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row sign_up_date                sign_up_date_as_timestamp    
1   2019-06-14T11:31:07         2019-06-14 11:31:07 UTC  
2   2019-05-25T05:31:22.7263555 2019-05-25 05:31:22.726355 UTC   
3   2019-06-14T09:09            2019-06-14 09:09:00 UTC
```

As you can see this will cover all three patters you presented in your question.
If you will find more - you can add respective SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP inside COALESCE